# How can I turn picture to structured dataframe?

Tags: r, image, dataframe

I would like to classify pictures by using R software. I have no knowledge in image processing so it will be great if someone would point me to the right direction. First, how can I turn a picture that I have into a structured dataframe so I'll be able to analyze it? Is there a package for this task? Second, Is there a defined process for picture classification that I can follow?

Comment: it would be useful when you can provide more information what you want: 1) you mean with turn rotate the image by 90° or 180°? 2) you want to classify the picture by which property? 3) what you want to analyze in your picture?

Comment: Hello @and, I would like to process pictures of different skin problems and I have sample JPEG images that I took with my digital camera (12MP ). How can I turn them into a data frame for analysis ( each row contains as many attributes as I can)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this lines you can load images in R and store them in a list.

```
library(jpeg)

setwd("path/to/folder/with/images/")
pics <- dir()

all_images <- NULL 
for(z in pics){
  all_images[[z]] <- readJPEG(z, native = T)
}

# check the first image in the list
plot(1:2, type='n')
rasterImage(all_images[[1]],1,1,2,2)
```

for processing images you can use the `imager` package.

Comment: I used the code on win7 default pictures but I got an error:"Error in readJPEG(z, native = T) :   JPEG decompression error: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xfe".However, I used the "Lighthouse" picture that is a JPEG format.What could be the problem?